# Maya 2018.1 python workspaceControl not remembering State

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to use workspaceControl in Maya 2018.1 and have been hitting a wall in it not remembering it's last position.  I could use a hand in finding out why.

Place this in your script folder as BBTest.py:

```
# BBTest.py
import pymel.core as pm

WorkspaceName = 'WorkspaceWinBoo'

class BBTest(object):
    def StartUI(self):
        if pm.workspaceControl( WorkspaceName, query=True, exists=True) is False:
            pm.workspaceControl( WorkspaceName, uiScript = 'from BBTest import curUI\ncurUI.buildUI()', closeCommand='from BBTest import curUI\ncurUI.CloseUI()')
        else:
            pm.workspaceControl( WorkspaceName, edit=True, restore=True)

    def CloseUI(self):
        if pm.workspaceControl( WorkspaceName, query=True, exists=True):
            pm.workspaceControl( WorkspaceName, edit=True, close=True )


    def buildUI(self):
        WinLayout = pm.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
        pm.button( label='Do Nothing' )
        pm.button( label='Close', command=pm.Callback(self.CloseUI) )

curUI = BBTest()
```

and spawn/restore it using this in your script editor or as a python shelf button:

```
import BBTest
BBTest.curUI.StartUI()
```

This will generate a little dockable window.  If you move it around and dock it then close it (via any means), it won't remember where it was docked.  It does remember size changes though.

If you dock it and quit Maya (with "Autosave workspace" enabled on your current workspace), Maya will start up and show the dialog docked, but if you close it for any reason, it will respawn as a floating window again.

How do I get it to remember it's dock state?

Comment: I can confirm that I'm having the same issue. It docks when it first opens, but then after it closes it only opens as a floating window.

Comment: Hey Green Cell, I found a solution was to save the tool's state for the current workspace by using the workspace's option button (Windows > Layouts > (name of your workspace) > []" and turning off "automatically save workspace layout".  Save your layout with the tool docked and it will be remembered on restart after closing.

Answer (score 0):

So through more formal testing, I've discovered that using "closeCommand" prevents workspaceControl from remembering state.

If anyone knows what I could call in my own close routine to restore that functionality, I would love to know.

There are other issues, but that's up to Autodesk's implementation and there's not a thing I can do about that aside from file bugs.